# What this error means (JetBrains Rider + Ubuntu Gnome 17.04)?

Tags: rider, ubuntu-17.04

I created Class Library project, then i see this:

> Project 'pldl.DataProvider' load failed
>             Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>             --- EXCEPTION #1/1 [NullReferenceException]
>             Message = “Object reference not set to an instance of an object”
>             ExceptionPath = Root
>             ClassName = System.NullReferenceException
>             HResult = E_POINTER=COR_E_NULLREFERENCE=80004003
>             Source = JetBrains.Platform.RdFramework
>             StackTraceString = “at JetBrains.Platform.RdFramework.Tasks.RdEndpoint`2+<>c__DisplayClassa[TReq,TRes].b__7 (JetBrains.Platform.RdFramework.SerializationCtx ctx, JetBrains.Util.Persisten
>   In solution explorer i see project file "loading failed"

Comment: Help -> Show logs in ...

Comment: Could you zip all logs and create an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: I think it is a bug somewhere in Rider =)

Answer (score 2):

solved by installing mono-devel